# HOWTO make part of WPF TextBlock text bold without embbed another TextBlock and using property setter

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, textblock

I have below TexBlock and I should change dynamically its text property based on the value selected on a WPF Combobox.

```
<TextBlock Padding="5 10 0 0">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
           <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select the items:" />
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWPFCombo, Path=Id}" Value="10">
                   <Setter Property="Text" Value="Select the old items:" />
               </DataTrigger>                               
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

My problem is that I need to set part of the text "Select the old items:" to bold, only the part "old items". In other scenarios I know that it can be done embbeding a textblock within it by in this case I need to set it using the setter. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's fiddly because you need part of the textblock to be bold and I don't think you can collapse an inline.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Padding="5 10 0 0">
            <Run Text="Select the"/>
            <Bold>
                <Run>
                  <Run.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Run">
                      <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWPFCombo, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="10">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="old items:" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>                          
                    </Style>
                </Run.Style>
                </Run>
            </Bold>
            <Run>
               <Run.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Run">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="items:" />
                      <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyWPFCombo, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="10">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>                          
                    </Style>
                </Run.Style>                 

            </Run>
        </TextBlock>
        <ComboBox x:Name="MyWPFCombo" 
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Ok I will try, but there is not way to use html characters like <b>...</b> within the string to do the same?

Comment: xaml isn't html - I don't think there is any special character you can put in a string that will switch to bold.